# How to do execute a query loop inside of another query loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm, knex.js

so my question is, how i can achieve this: I have an array of dates and an array of locations, i want to iterate the array of dates, and for each date, execute some query's, them iterate the whole array of locations doing an query for each item and them return an JSON response with the data.

**P.S. I am using TypeOrm and i am also novice**

Comment: Could you explain more with example code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got two arrays, and you want to loop one inside of the other, then... just do that.

```js
var locations = ['Paris','St Louis','Moscow'];
var dates = ['wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday'];

async function run(locations, dates) {
  let results = [];
  
  for (let location of locations) {
    for (let date of dates) {
      console.log(`${location} - ${date}`);
      const newResults = await query(location, date);
      results = results.concat(newResults);
    }
  }
  
  return results;
}

run(locations, dates);
```

edited to include async query example

Comment: sorry, i think i didn't explained it well, the code is meant to do query's inside an database, that's why i said im using typeorm.

Comment: so then make your query inside the internal loop. that's fine mate.

Comment: Your query is likely async (it either deals with callbacks or promises), so make sure you're running this function inside a function labeled `async` and await the result of the query if possible.

Comment: @BrunoD. I've edited my answer to show what an async query example might possibly look like

Comment: just giving an update here, worked perfectly! My first attempts where using array.map but your approach worked very well, thanks man.